# Программа для peer-to-peer голосования

Tags: c, p2p

Такую, чтобы просто скачать, поставить и пользоваться.
Опенсорсную, желательно на C# или C++.

**Обновление**

Проблему я вижу в том, что не существует ни одной такой программы. Хотя теоретически в мире есть все необходимые знания для её написания (в википедии, например, описаны разные алгоритмы голосований, алгоритм DHT и другие).

Comment: @ish, Вопросы опросники запрещены в сообществе. Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему и т. д.

Comment: Проблему я вижу в том, что не существует ни одной такой программы. Хотя теоретически в мире есть все необходимые знания для её написания (в википедии, например, описаны разные алгоритмы голосований, алгоритм DHT и другие).

Comment: @ish, так опишите свое видение понятным для всех программистов образом, требования к такой программе и среде, в которой она должна работать  
(а главное, что такое peer-to-peer голосование, кто и как будет им пользоваться).